# How to set trust level?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-config, medium-trust

My web hosting's configurations is requesting me to create a trust nevel and set it to menimum to my web site. I did some search and found on ASP.NET 4+ it's done by adding this to web.config:

```
 <securityPolicy>
      <trustLevel name="Medium" 
                  policyFile="internal.config"
       />
    </securityPolicy>
```

But this doesn't show any of example what internal.config is like. Would anyone give me an example?

Comment: what hosting do you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set full trust level add this code to web.config

```
<system.web>   
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" /> 
</system.web>
```